# When does the Stack Overflow week start?

Tags: discussion, recent-activity, reputation-leagues, time

I assume it's either Sunday at 0 GMT or Monday at 0 GMT but I've tried checking a few things and searching and can't find when it is.  This is in regards to the [weekly reputation leagues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users) and "this week" and "last week" tabs of the [recent activity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/) page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hover your mouse over the week, month, quarter and year buttons on the users page, there is a date range for each.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  Is it just me, or is it absolutely crazy that the top users are getting 400 rep per day, without bounties?  This means that in addition to getting 20 upvotes per day (which is nothing at their level), they are getting at least 14 accepted answers per day, every day.

Comment: @Pollyanna: for me, 400 rep is a good day but not exceptional. 500 is pretty rare. 300 would be disappointing (on a week day, assuming I'm not on holiday). Anything less than 300 would be slightly embarrassing. On the weekend, 300 is reasonably gratifying.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I can't find these.  Anymore.  The "recent activity" link in the OQ is dead, by the way, so it looks like some redesign did away with it. :-(  Which leaves this question open (again).