# When does weekly league update and when does server's week start?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

I saw [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81577/when-does-the-stack-overflow-week-start) question, but I'm not sure if I get it.

- Does SO week start on Monday or on Sunday?
- When does weekly league update (which day could we see current week statistics (in this case  Jul 17, 2011 -  Jul 24, 2011))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stack Exchange week starts on a Sunday at 00:00 UTC.

You can see this as your Today reputation equals your Week reputation (until 23:59 UTC!)

Comment: however if you look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=week) you'll see that Jon Skeet received 215, and it's today's reputation...

Comment: @genesis - it's not unknown for Jon to break the reputation cap before he posts an answer.

Comment: but when week starts on Sunday (before 16 hours). So weekly league updates once a day, it means that I'll see John in league tomorrow at 0:00 ?